# Scale the video up from a smaller size(Re-scale)

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, video-processing

I'm actually looking for is to not just the quality but resize the entire video to a greater resolution using the AV foundation.
I have a videos in `320x240` and `176x144` in mp4 quality and I want to resize video upto size `1280x720`, but `AVAssetExportSession` class not allow to scale the video up from a smaller size.

Answer (score 1):

try AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction and CGAffineTransform.

This code will help the understanding.

https://gist.github.com/zrxq/9817265