# AVFoundation exporting orientation wrong

Tags: ios, swift, camera, orientation, avassetexportsession

I'm attempting to combine an image and a video. I have them combining and exporting however it's rotated side ways.

Sorry for the bulk code paste. I've seen answers about applying a transform to `compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform` however that does nothing. Adding to `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction` does nothing also.

I feel like this area is where things start to go wrong. here here:

```
// I feel like this loading here is the problem
        let videoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

        // because it makes our parentLayer and videoLayer sizes wrong
        let videoSize       = videoTrack.naturalSize

        // this is returning 1920x1080, so it is rotating the video
        print("\(videoSize.width) , \(videoSize.height)")
```

So by here our frame sizes are wrong for the rest of the method. Now when we try to go and create the overlay image layer the frame is not correct:

```
    let aLayer = CALayer()
    aLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "OverlayTestImageOverlay")?.CGImage
    aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height)
    aLayer.opacity = 1
```

Here is my complete method.

```
  func combineImageVid() {

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SampleMovie", ofType:"MOV")
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: fileURL)
        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

        let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

        var clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do {
            try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), ofTrack: clipVideoTrack[0], atTime: kCMTimeZero)
        }
        catch _ {
            print("failed to insertTimeRange")
        }


        compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = videoAsset.preferredTransform

        // I feel like this loading here is the problem
        let videoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

        // because it makes our parentLayer and videoLayer sizes wrong
        let videoSize       = videoTrack.naturalSize

        // this is returning 1920x1080, so it is rotating the video
        print("\(videoSize.width) , \(videoSize.height)")

        let aLayer = CALayer()
        aLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "OverlayTestImageOverlay")?.CGImage
        aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height)
        aLayer.opacity = 1


        let parentLayer     = CALayer()
        let videoLayer      = CALayer()

        parentLayer.frame   = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height)
        videoLayer.frame    = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height)

        parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
        parentLayer.addSublayer(aLayer)


        let videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        videoComp.renderSize = videoSize
        videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
        videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, inLayer: parentLayer)

        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

        instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)

        let mixVideoTrack = mixComposition.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
        mixVideoTrack.preferredTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI * 90.0 / 180))

        let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: mixVideoTrack)
        instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
        videoComp.instructions = [instruction]


        //  create new file to receive data
        let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let docsDir: AnyObject = dirPaths[0]
        let movieFilePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("result.mov")
        let movieDestinationUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: movieFilePath)

        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(movieFilePath)
        }
        catch _ {}


        // use AVAssetExportSession to export video
        let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
        assetExport?.videoComposition = videoComp
        assetExport!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
        assetExport!.outputURL = movieDestinationUrl
        assetExport!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
            switch assetExport!.status{
            case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
                print("failed \(assetExport!.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(assetExport!.error)")
            default:
                print("Movie complete")


                // play video
                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                    print(movieDestinationUrl)
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

This is what I'm getting exported: 
[image]

---

I tried adding these two methods in order to rotate the video:

```
class func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)

    let assetTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

    let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
    let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform)
    var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width

    if assetInfo.isPortrait {

        scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
        let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToFitRatio, scaleToFitRatio)
        instruction.setTransform(CGAffineTransformConcat(assetTrack.preferredTransform, scaleFactor),
            atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    } else {

        let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToFitRatio, scaleToFitRatio)
        var concat = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(assetTrack.preferredTransform, scaleFactor), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2))
        if assetInfo.orientation == .Down {
            let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
            let windowBounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
            let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + windowBounds.height
            let centerFix = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(assetTrack.naturalSize.width, yFix)
            concat = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(fixUpsideDown, centerFix), scaleFactor)
        }
        instruction.setTransform(concat, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    }

    return instruction
}

class func orientationFromTransform(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
    var assetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.Up
    var isPortrait = false
    if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .Right
        isPortrait = true
    } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .Left
        isPortrait = true
    } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .Up
    } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .Down
    }
    return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
}
```

The updated my `combineImageVid()` method adding this in

```
let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)

let mixVideoTrack = mixComposition.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

//let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: mixVideoTrack)
//layerInstruction.setTransform(videoAsset.preferredTransform, atTime: kCMTimeZero)

let layerInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(compositionVideoTrack, asset: videoAsset)
```

Which gives me this output:

[image]

So I'm getting closer however I feel that because the track is originally being loaded the wrong way, I need to address the issue there. Also, I don't know why the huge black box is there now. I thought maybe it was due to my image layer taking the bounds of the loaded video asset here:

```
aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height)
```

However changing that to some small width/height doesn't make a difference. I then thought about adding a crop rec to get rid of the black square but that didn't work either :(

---

Following Allens suggestions of not using these two methods:

```
class func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction

class func orientationFromTransform(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool)
```

But updating my original method to look like this:

```
videoLayer.frame    = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.height, videoSize.width) //notice the switched width and height
...
videoComp.renderSize = CGSizeMake(videoSize.height,videoSize.width) //this make the final video in portrait
...
layerInstruction.setTransform(videoTrack.preferredTransform, atTime: kCMTimeZero) //important piece of information let composition know you want to rotate the original video in output
```

We are getting really close however the problem now seems to be editing `renderSize`. If I change it to anything other than the landscape size I get this:

[image]

Comment: This link here might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034337/how-to-export-video-asset-via-avassetexportsession-in-portrait-mode

Comment: I've tried that as well :( I appreciate the suggest though.

Comment: Can you try changing this in combineImageVid() method --- compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);

Comment: @AnkitGupta doesn't help at all :( it seems to never respect that setting

Answer (score 21, accepted):

here is the document for the orientation at Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1744/_index.html

if your original video was taken in portrait mode iOS, it's nature size will still be landscape, but it comes with a metadata of rotate in the mov file. In order to rotate your video, you need to make changes to your 1st piece of code with the following:

```
videoLayer.frame    = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.height, videoSize.width) //notice the switched width and height
...
videoComp.renderSize = CGSizeMake(videoSize.height,videoSize.width) //this make the final video in portrait
...
layerInstruction.setTransform(videoTrack.preferredTransform, atTime: kCMTimeZero) //important piece of information let composition know you want to rotate the original video in output
```

Yes, you are really close!

Comment: I appreciate the help! We are getting really close however there seems to be an issue when changing the `renderSize`. I've updated any question with a .gif of what's going on.

Comment: @random, are you running in simulator? then don't, run it in real iOS device, the simulator can't do the translation well.

Comment: yup, running it in the simulator was the problem! You're awesome, thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: I tried this code and it works with the back camera, but in front still getting the same result. The video is at the right orientation but cut in half.

Comment: check link for front Camera https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818429/avassetexportsession-wrong-orientation-in-front-camera?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: if self.currentCamera == .front {
        movieFileOutputConnection?.isVideoMirrored = false
}

Comment: @Dania Yes, but how can we do this with a mirrored front camera?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe U should check the videoTrack's preferredTransform so to give it a exact renderSize and transform:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = assetVideoTrack.preferredTransform;
CGFloat rotation = [self rotationWithTransform:transform]; 
//if been rotated
        if (rotation != 0)
        {
            //if rotation is 360°
            if (fabs((rotation - M_PI * 2)) >= valueOfError) {

                CGFloat m = rotation / M_PI;
                CGAffineTransform t1;
                //rotation is 90° or 270°
                if (fabs(m - 1/2.0) < valueOfError || fabs(m - 3/2.0) < valueOfError) {
                    self.mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height,assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.width);
                    t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, 0);
                }
                //rotation is 180°
                if (fabs(m - 1.0) < valueOfError) {
                    t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.width, assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height);
                }
                CGAffineTransform t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1,rotation);
                //                CGAffineTransform transform = makeTransform(1.0, 1.0, 90, videoTrack.naturalSize.height, 0);
                [passThroughLayer setTransform:t2 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
            }
        }

//convert transform to radian
- (CGFloat)rotationWithTransform:(CGAffineTransform)t
{
    return atan2f(t.b, t.a);
}
```

Comment: sorry, I have translate the expanation. @luk2302